# Files appear when I try to attach from Desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I'm using Windows 7 and Internet Explorer. There are 4 folders and a .pdf file on my desktop. When I login to gmail.com, create a new email and click attach, the window that shows my desktop shows more items than my desktop has. It shows about 20 more files that my desktop doesn't have.

Why is this happening? How can I get rid of this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: How many files are actually on your desktop? (E.g. check C:\Users\yourusernamehere\Desktop). Are there any off-screen? Did you set windows explorer to hide files?